# Ambiguous invocation error when adding join to dbContext query

Tags: linq, lambda, dbcontext

I have been working for hours to get something done that would take me about a minute with TSQL. When I add the join statement to this method VS complains about an ambiguous invocation. When I mouse over ".Where" the pop-up hint runs across one monitor into another, so it's hard for me to extract anything very helpful from it. If I comment out the .Join clause everything is happy.

Thanks for any guidance.

```
        public List<CategoryDto> Categories(int departmentId)
    {
        IQueryable<CategoryDto> categories = null;
        List<CategoryDto> categoriesList = null;
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            categories = context.Categories
                .Join(context.CategoryImages, j => j.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId,
                    (j, c) => new { CategoryImages = j, Categories = c })
                .Where(c => c.DepartmentId == departmentId)
                .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                .Select(category => new CategoryDto
                {
                    CategoryId = category.CategoryId,
                    DepartmentId = category.DepartmentId,
                    Name = category.Name,
                    Description = category.Description,
                    DisplayOrderRank = category.DisplayOrderRank,
                    IsActive = category.IsActive
                });
            if (categories != null) categoriesList = categories.ToList();
        }
        return categoriesList;
    }
```

Comment: When your dealing with joins, the statement syntax is a lot easier to understand.  Something like `from c in context.Categories join j in context.CategoryImages on j.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId...`.  Just make sure to always refer to the fields with a `j` or `c` prefix after the join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using...

```
.Join(context.CategoryImages, j => j.CategoryId, c => c.CategoryId,
                (j, c) => new { CategoryImages = j, Categories = c })
```

... you create an `IQueryable<T>` where T is an anonymous type having two properties, `CategoryImages` and `Categories` (although you've got them in the wrong order, and also it's better to use singular words). So you have to continue the LINQ statement by using this anonymous type, like ...

```
.Where(x => x.Categories.DepartmentId == departmentId)
```

As said in the comment, with joins comprehensive syntax is way easier:

```
from c in context.Categories
join i in context.CategoryImages on c.CategoryId equals i.CategoryId
where c.DepartmentId == departmentId // now this is OK
```

But even better is not to write a join at all and use navigation properties, like `Category.Images`. By the way, I'm not sure why you're accessing `Images`, because you don't use them in the end result. Currently the only effect of the join is that you may get non-unique categories.

Comment: Thanks Gert. I marked yours as the answer because of the insight into the problem you provided. As for why Images wasn't in the DTO, I hadn't added it because I hadn't figured out how to write the query. Just a few minutes ago I realized I can use eager loading and my problem was solved. I replaced the .Join with .Include(i => i.CategoryImages), and of course I added Images to the DTO